# Is it advisable to route the user to the main function from another function?

Tags: c, menu

I am new to coding and I have heard that calling the main function is bad practice, however I don't see another way to make it possible to navigate back and forth in a menu other than the way I did in this code.  Is what I did here "calling" the main function?  is this legal?

Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MAINmenu();
void menu1();
void menu2();
int m;

int main()
{
    MAINmenu();
}
void MAINmenu()
{
    printf("MAIN MENU\tplease choose menu 1, menu 2, or 3 to quit\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    do
    {
        switch(m)
        {
            case 1:
                menu1();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu2();
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("GOODBYE");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR.\n");
                main();
                break;
        }
    }while(m!=3);
}
void menu1()
{
    printf("MENU 1.\n");
    printf("would you like to continue here(1) or go back to main(2)?\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    switch(m)
    {
        case 1:
            menu1();
            break;
        case 2:
            main();
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR.\n");
            menu1();
            break;
    }
}
void menu2()
{
    printf("MENU 2.\n");
    printf("would you like to continue here(1) or go back to main(2)?\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    switch(m)
    {
        case 1:
            menu2();
            break;
        case 2:
            main();
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR.\n");
            menu2();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `main()` is entirely legal. It is also very rare, and for good reason.

Comment: Note: This will *eventually* lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: 'while(1) MAINmenu();'  to run the main menu again, return from the MAINmenu() function anywhere you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
int main()
{
    while (MAINmenu());
    return 0;
}
int MAINmenu()
{
    printf("MAIN MENU\tplease choose menu 1, menu 2, or 3 to quit\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    do
    {
        switch(m)
        {
            case 1:
                menu1();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu2();
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("GOODBYE");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR.\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }while(m!=3);
    return 0;
}
...
```

But call main() can be ok too.